# Set CSS Font Size With Drop Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add live update font size list box to a project and I cant seem to get it to work.

I've add a HTML font size selector and some java-script to an existing working project with no luck, I cant seem to figure it out as it looks complete to me and I think it should work.

Here is my code that I'm using.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css" />

    <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

    <style>
     body { padding:50px; background-color:#333;}
    p, h1 { color:#fff;}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#font').fontselect().change(function(){

          // replace + signs with spaces for css
          var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

          // split font into family and weight
          font = font.split(':');

          // set family on paragraphs
          $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
        });
      });

    </script>

  <script>
      $("#size").change(function() {
      $('p').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
     });      
   </script>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <input id="font" type="text" />

    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
     Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
     when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
     specimen book.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have put back the original code that you posted. Changing the code to show your attempt at implementing one of the answers provided here makes your question (and the answers provided) make no sense to others who will come along and read them. If you have new questions about implementing one of the suggested answers, just add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is beginning to refuse to download links from non-encrypted sources in an effort to combat phishing fraud and you can read more about that [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-is-requiring-https-for-secure-data-in-chrome/183756/).

So, the issue is that your `<script>` links to download the JQuery and fontselect libraries are being done via **http** and not **https** and your browser is not downloading them because of that.

Change:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/l...
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-F...
```

To:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/l...
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-F...
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#font').fontselect().change(function(){

    // replace + signs with spaces for css
    var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

    // split font into family and weight
    font = font.split(':');

    // set family on paragraphs
    $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
  });
});
     
$("#size").change(function() {
  $('p').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css">

    <style>
     body { padding:50px; background-color:#333;}
    p, h1 { color:#fff;}
    </style>


    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <input id="font" type="text" />

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

---

### With that said and done, this feature is incredibly easy to implement yourself, without any external libraries at all:

```js
// First, get a reference to the drop down and the target element
var dd = document.getElementById("size");
var target = document.querySelector("p");

// Then, set up an event handling function for when the value of the select changes
dd.addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Remove the previously applied class
  target.className = "";
  // Just apply the CSS class that corresponds to the size selected
  target.classList.add(dd.value);
});
```

```css
body { padding:50px; background-color:#333;}
p, h1 { color:#fff;}

/* CSS class names must start with a letter */
.seven { font-size:7px; }
.ten { font-size:10px; }
.twenty { font-size:20px; }
.thirty { font-size:30px; }
```

```html
<select id="size">
  <option value="">Choose a font size...</option>  
 <!-- The values here must match the names of the CSS classes -->
  <option value="seven">7</option>
  <option value="ten">10</option>
  <option value="twenty">20</option>
  <option value="thirty">30</option>
</select>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

Comment: Scott , I have updated the code see top post and I still get a error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of "addEventListener" of null

Comment: @Blnukem That's because you have added the `<script>` tag before the elements in the page that the script works with have been loaded. Move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the code, just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`).

Comment: @Blnukem Also, you don't need two `script` tags for the custom code. Combine them together as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: @Blnukem  Lastly, you have combined the fontselect solution as well as my alternate solution (that removes the need for JQuery and fontselect), which you shouldn't do. Choose one of the solutions I provided, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated answer with code snippet. the problems are: 1) missing `<html><head>` at top, 2) missing jquery package, 3) fonteselect.js and fontselect.css need to be called with https://, not http://.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css" />

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

<style>
 body { padding:50px; background-color:#333;}
p, h1 { color:#fff;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  $(function(){
 $('#font').fontselect().change(function(){

   // replace + signs with spaces for css
   var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

   // split font into family and weight
   font = font.split(':');

   // set family on paragraphs
   $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
 });
  });

</script>

<script>
  $("#size").change(function() {
  $('p').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
 });
</script>

<select id="size">
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<input id="font" type="text" />

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't post code at 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time. Just post your code right here (as a code snippet) in your answer (see my answer for an example).

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure you have the jQuery library linked to in your document. Then, make sure that `$(this).val()` gives you a correct value.